# Can I always see the other module?

Tags: wifi, range

I am planning to set up an ESP8266 mesh network. If node A receives beacons from node B, does this mean node B can receive beacons from node A? Assume they are the same (same antenna, ...)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_node_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in the absence of environmental RF noise at either end, if you have two identical systems then if node 1 can hear node 2, then node 2 should be able to hear node 1.

However, if you can imagine a situation where you are upstairs in a house and people are sitting watching TV downstairs and you can hear them talking fairly quietly between themselves - you could be shouting quite loudly but they would not hear you because of the sound of the TV.

The same would apply in a WiFi network where node 1 has a lot of local noise (nearby microwave oven, BlueTooth devices, anything that uses frequencies at or near the 2.4GHz or 5GHz that it is using), then node 2 might be able to hear node 1 perfectly clearly but node 1 would not hear anything above the local noise.